# Не засчитали посещение сайта при заходе с телефона

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Вчера посещал сайт **SO** и у меня в профиле было написано, что на сайте столько-то дней подряд. А сегодня 1 день подряд. Восстановить значение можно? *Заходил вчера с телефона.*

Comment: Судя по графику, в субботу вы не заходили =/

Comment: Возможно есть косяк с учётом, если сидишь с телефона. Нужно проверить.

Comment: @Suvitruf по удалённому вопросу в чате ответил.  Заходил утром по МСК.  В истории хрома нет точного времени.

Comment: Утром - это во сколько? Там подсчёт вроде как по UTC в 00:00.

Comment: @Suvitruf в промежутке от 8-00 до 10-00.

Comment: "С телефона" = с телефона в браузере или мобильное приложение использовали?

Comment: Какие именно действия делали?

Comment: @Suvitruf Мобильное приложение — [Chrome by Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=ru)

Comment: @Suvitruf может и нет..не помню.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно как следует проверить.

Пока нашёл такое обсуждение: [Last seen not updating when using Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191781/260198). Там сотрудник ответил:

> As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only those actions we consider "real". For the mobile app, this basically means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we consider "real" over time.

Перевод:

> Мы не трекаем все действия. Учитываются только "реальные" действия. Для мобильного приложения это означает, что просто открытие списка вопросов не засчитывается как активность.

Полного списка "реальных" действий я не нашёл.

Comment: Это форшмак....